# One-to-one relationship with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am creating a Twitter clone for fun, and am having some issues with the Sequelize relationship side of things.

**My objective** is to create a *many-to-one* relationship for:  *User*-to-*Tweets*

And then create a *one-to-one* relationship for: *Tweet*-to-*User*

I have successfully completed the *many-to-one* relationship in my tweet.js file, which you can see here:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Tweet = sequelize.define('Tweet', {
    tweet: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        //creating a one-to-many relationship from user->tweets
        models.User.hasMany(models.Tweet, {as: 'tweets'});
      }
    }
  });
  return Tweet;
};
```

However, in my *user.js* where I intend to create the *one-to-one* relationship from: *Tweet*-to-*User*, I am having issues.

I tried following the documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#associating-objects), but I cannot get this relationship to create successfully. Here is an example of my current code:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
      //classMethod guarantees the password provided by the user matches what's in the db
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          //associate every tweet to having one author (User)
          models.Tweet.hasOne(models.User, { as: "Author" });
          models.Tweet#setAuthor(anAuthor);
        }
      }
    });
  return User;
}; //**Note that 'models' contains two objects: 'Tweet' and 'User'**
```

I'm not sure how to handle this relationship, how can I create a one-to-one relationship from Tweet-to-User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, maybe this will help you:

```
       module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
            var Tweet = sequelize.define('Tweet', {
            tweet: DataTypes.TEXT
              }, {
                classMethods: {
                   associate: function(models) {
                   Tweet.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'tweets'})
              }
           }
      });
       return Tweet;
  };



    module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
         var User = sequelize.define('Users', {
                   username: DataTypes.STRING,
                   password: DataTypes.STRING
           }, {
    //classMethod guarantees the password provided by the user matches     what's in the db
           classMethods: {
                   associate: function (models) {
                   User.hasMany(models.Tweet, {as: "Author"})

                 }
            }
        });
           return User;
     };
```